# Jackson ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY and PolymorphicTypeValidator not working together

Tags: java, json, jackson, pmml

Hello everyone I'm having problem when deserializing from XML/JSON PMML into JPMML class model specifically to DefineFunction class.
Using normal approach without any modifiers with following snippet:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 DefineFunction readValue = mapper.readValue(readValueAsTree.toString(), DefineFunction.class);
```

yields error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<org.dmg.pmml.ParameterField>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

Which is understandable, because in ParameterField attribute is a new ParamField object directly and not expected array.
So after changing the snippet accordingly to allow single values as arrays:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
DefineFunction readValue = mapper.readValue(readValueAsTree.toString(), DefineFunction.class);
```

yields error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "MapValues" (class org.dmg.pmml.DefineFunction), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "ParameterField", "dataType", "Expression", "name", "Extension", "optype"])
```

Which is also fine, since the problem is parsing of "expression" field in DefineFunction which is abstract class.
So after changing the snippet again to also allow the polymorfic values:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
                .activateDefaultTyping(BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder().build());
DefineFunction readValue = mapper.readValue(readValueAsTree.toString(), DefineFunction.class);
```

the jackson gives me following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class java.util.List
```

which seems to refer to missing *@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)* annotation at the *parameterFields* property of DefineFunction class model.
Unfortunatelly i cannot edit the JPMML class model in any way to try, if this would solve the issue.
Adding polymorfic support seems to produce additional error with previous ParameterField field, which is why i titled the question this way.

#### The question

Is there a way for me to deserialize the input to the JPMML class model? I would prefer to avoid writting my own parser for the whole DefineFunction class, since that would defeat the purpose of the Jackson library as well as there are more classes like this in the full model, which makes it more difficult. Thank you for any suggestions.

#### The input:

```
{
"name":"functionName",
"optype":"categorical",
"dataType":"double",
"ParameterField":{"name":"someField","optype":"categorical","dataType":"string"},
"MapValues":{"defaultValue":"0","outputColumn":"out","dataType":"double",
    "FieldColumnPair":{"field":"medId","column":"id"},
    "InlineTable":{"row":{"id":"1","out":"0.1"}}
  }
}
```

#### The class model (shortened for readability):

```
public class DefineFunction
extends org.dmg.pmml.PMMLObject
{

@XmlAttribute(name = "name", required = true)
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@XmlAttribute(name = "optype", required = true)
@JsonProperty("optype")
private OpType opType;
@XmlAttribute(name = "dataType")
@JsonProperty("dataType")
private DataType dataType;
@XmlElement(name = "Extension", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4")
@JsonProperty("Extension")
private List<Extension> extensions;
@XmlElement(name = "ParameterField", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", required = true)
@JsonProperty("ParameterField")
private List<ParameterField> parameterFields;
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "Constant", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.Constant.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "FieldRef", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.FieldRef.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "NormContinuous", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.NormContinuous.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "NormDiscrete", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.NormDiscrete.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "Discretize", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.Discretize.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "MapValues", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.MapValues.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "TextIndex", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.TextIndex.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "Apply", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.Apply.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "Aggregate", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.Aggregate.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "Lag", namespace = "http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", type = org.dmg.pmml.Lag.class)
})
@JsonProperty("Expression")
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Constant", value = org.dmg.pmml.Constant.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "FieldRef", value = org.dmg.pmml.FieldRef.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "NormContinuous", value = org.dmg.pmml.NormContinuous.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "NormDiscrete", value = org.dmg.pmml.NormDiscrete.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Discretize", value = org.dmg.pmml.Discretize.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "MapValues", value = org.dmg.pmml.MapValues.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "TextIndex", value = org.dmg.pmml.TextIndex.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Apply", value = org.dmg.pmml.Apply.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Aggregate", value = org.dmg.pmml.Aggregate.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Lag", value = org.dmg.pmml.Lag.class)
})
private Expression expression;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You should use the `org.jpmml.model.jackson.JacksonUtil` utility class for reading and writing JPMML class model objects in JSON data format. Its part of the JPMML-Model library (`org.jpmml:pmml-model-jackson` module).

Where did you get your JSON fragment from? Crafted manually? It doesn't match the annotations that are present in the `DefineFunction` class.

Writing a dummy `DefineFunction` object into a JSON file:

```
DefineFunction defineFunction = new DefineFunction()
  .addParameterFields(new ParameterField())
  .setExpression(new MapValues());

try(OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("df.json"){
  JacksonUtil.write(defineFunction, os);
}
```

Therefore, the correct JSON structure should look like this:

```
{
  "DefineFunction" : {
    "ParameterField" : [ { } ],
    "Expression" : {
      "MapValues" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

A correct JSON file reads successfully:

```
try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream("df.json"){
  DefineFunction defineFunction = JacksonUtil.read(DefineFunction.class, is);
}
```

Comment: If you look at the JacksonUtil bytecode, it does exactly the same as i do using Jackson directly. It just saves you some lines of code. They are using DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE and SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE though, which is not helpful here.
The JSON comes from its XML counterpart, that i read using XmlMapper jackson ObjectMapper wrapper, where you also get just one value for ParameterField. And that comes from different app, where it is generated using JAXB and some older PMML model, which only differs in not having Expression abstract parent class yet.